# The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install. Trying to dual boot Kali-Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios, kali

I'm trying to configure a dual boot between Kali Linux and Ubuntu. I have already installed Kali in one partition with about 40G. The rest of the size will be asigned to install Ubuntu. This is how my kali linux partitions looks:

[Kali partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyg0T.jpg)

As you see the kali linux is encrypted with luks and use lvm. I want to do the same with the Ubuntu distro. I have created the partitions for ubuntu like this:

[Ubuntu installation partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRhvU.jpg)

the /dev/sda4 is the partition where i need to put ubuntu.

This is the lvm configuration, with a root filesystem and a swap.

[Ubuntu lvm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAyL3.jpg)

Then when i try to install ubuntu, it show this error
**The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/ . Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot**

I'm using uefi to install the partitions.

What i've done wrong with this setup?

Comment: I answered a nearly identical question a few days ago with a step-by-step.  If you want the installation to be encrypted, you need to create a separate boot partition.  Otherwise the boot instructions will be encrypted and your system won't know what to do.  see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246401/lukslvm-without-wiping-the-hard-drive/1247047#1247047

Comment: Does this answer your question? [16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)

Comment: @Nmath I followed your guide but it dind't work for me. keep throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after trying a lot of things i finally could get rid out this error. I decided to reformat the usb where i was booting to install ubuntu. I made this usb bootable with rufus inside win10, i reformat it inside Debian 9 and then make use of the dd command. Then i boot on it again and the installation continued without problems.

**Note**
This is the guide i followed to create the partitions and to be able to boot

https://vitobotta.com/2018/01/11/ubuntu-full-disk-encryption-manual-partitioning-uefi/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I have 512GB SDD and 1TB HDD. I wanted to install Ubuntu 18.04 on HDD while Win10 (UEFI) is installed on SDD. I solved the problem as follows:

1. Create a bootable USB with Ubuntu 18.04 (choose partition scheme: GPT -this was the issue key point I was using BIOS-EFI while it's important to have only EFI).
2. Enter the BIOS setting screen and disable secure boot, besides disabling the fast boot. Enable boot from USB hard disk.
3. I prepared the partitions of the HDD while installing Ubuntu as follow:

   - 500 MB partition for EFI
   - 16000 MB for swap area (some blogs I read suggested to size the swap
     area minimum as the memory size: in my case= 16GB)
   - I kept the rest of the  free size as ex4  for the root directory (you can do partition as you need: / and /home ...)
4. Start installing and have fun!  (in case the Grub boot load hasn't shown while startup you can enter into the boot screen or BIOS setting to add ubuntu as the first boot choice ).