# Kubuntu and Windows 10 on a single encrypted LVM SSD

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, windows-10, lvm

I want to install Kubuntu 20.04. (encryprted LVM) and Windows 10 on the same SSD disk. Kubuntu will delete and encrypt the full disk. How can install both in dual boot then? Normally I install Windows and then Kubuntu which sees Windows and adds Windows 10 to the boot menu. But now I have first to install Kubuntu because it deletes and encrypts the WHOLE disk.

In fact I have already Kubuntu (unencrypted) with Windows 10 working. Is it a way to encrypt Ubuntu partionon only? It would be easier then doing everything again from scratch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu with full disk encryption without having to “erase everything”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246401/lukslvm-without-wiping-the-hard-drive).  Please see the answer I've posted here.  You need to reinstall Ubuntu to set up full disk encryption.  You can do this using the manual "something else" option. - you can't encrypt an already-installed system.