# How to install Ubuntu 21.10 to a mapper device (to dual boot LUKS)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 21.10, luks

I tried to use [this very old post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918021/encrypted-custom-install) as a model to install directly to the LUKS mapper instead of to an LVM set on top of the mapper, but the Ubuntu 21.10 installer explicitly forbids installing to a mapper.

The basic TLDR of the old post was:

1. Boot in `try it` mode
2. Manually create the LUKS partition
3. Do a `luksOpen` on the partition
4. Point the installer at the "opened" partition
5. Post install click "continue testing"
6. Back in shell, make a `chroot`
7. In the `chroot` setup `fstab` and grub
8. Close out the `chroot` and reboot

Of course I'm failing on #4 since the installer wont let me install to a mapper device.

So, is there any way to use the single-partition setup that "Install alongside Windows" uses, but with LUKS enabled?  Possibly through scripted installs?  This is how I've gotten past some of the more exotic Microsoft prohibitions previously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu with full disk encryption without having to "erase everything"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246401/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-with-full-disk-encryption-without-having-to-erase-every). It's not that complicated! You can use the installer without having to use chroot or touch the terminal

Comment: I don't see where you've said what installer you're talking about. Ubuntu 21.10 has multiple ISOs available that use different installers; but you've not said if you're talking about a `ubiquity` installer/ISO, `subiquity` installer/ISO etc. The `ubiquity` installer has been available for many releases (decade+) but you've provided no specific details as to what you actually tried & had issues with.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Nmath, yes it does.  Thanks.  I had found that post earlier but didn't realize that it would work with a Win10 EFI install.  Having done the install 3 times now, the post makes much more sense.  Thanks for suggesting I reread it.

Comment: @guiverc, Think this post is a duplicate.  It was `ubiquity` I think.  Whatever the default installer is for `ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: Yep `ubiquity` is the default desktop installer for 21.10  (most *flavors* too but not Lubuntu or Ubuntu-Studio which use `calamares`), Ubuntu server installer being `subiquity`   (FYI:  There was the *canary* desktop installer ISO too that uses the desktop version of `subiquity` but it wasn't released thus it's *canary* status; it wasn't ready for 21.10)