# How to manually install Ubuntu 23.10 with ZFS and TPM-backed full disk encryption?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, zfs, tpm, 23.10

In Ubuntu 23.10, Mantic Manticore, the options for TPM-backed full disk encryption (FDE) and ZFS are both exclusive to the installer option that wipes my entire disk. I have other OSes on disk I don't want to wipe with an unformatted section I'd like to use for a new Mantic install.

How does a user format a drive with ZFS and encrypt a disk with TPM-backend full disk encryption without wiping their disk? This question is not a duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu with full disk encryption without having to "erase everything"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246401/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-with-full-disk-encryption-without-having-to-erase-every) as that covers a non-ZFS, non-TPM-backed FDE installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: "without wiping their disk"? By what magic are you going to do FDE without wiping the disk? AFAIK the only reasons Macs apparently allow enabling encryption without wiping is that the SSDs are already encrypted anyway, and all they really do is change the key.

Comment: @muru because the disk space for the install would be unformatted. I don't want to wipe the disk because there are other OSes on the disk.

Comment: @mpboden I have made an edit to the first paragraph adding context. Is that acceptable in your view or would you like if the title were edited too?