# Installing Ubuntu 23.10 on a separate NVME SSD than Windows 11 with Bitlocker

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, encryption

Yesterday I tried to get some help on fixing my grub2 after removing grub customizer and was unable to do so with any of the responses and my question was closed as resolved. I have decided it may be easier to just do a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Currently I have Windows 11 with Bitlocker enabled on a primary NVME SSD. Ubuntu is installed with luks encryption on a secondary NVME SSD.

When trying to install Ubuntu with the erase disk option it stops me saying the device has Bitlocker enabled. I logged into Windows and suspended Bitlocker and went straight back to booting from the install USB and it's still telling me Bitlocker is enabled and I can't proceed with choosing the Linux drive to write over.

Is there any other option or am I going to have to decrypt Windows entirely to do this and then encrypt again when I am done?

Comment: You may have to use the "Something else" option (I am not sure if it is still called that in 23.10 installer) and select the secondary NVME drive where Ubuntu is installed. I would try completely disable bitlocker and then re-enable it after Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: There is no something else option. There is install alongside Windows, erase disk and install (only one where I can use luks encryption), and manually create partitions. I can see the drives in the manually create partitions options, but I'm not to sure how to configure it and also use luks encryption. I would prefer not to have to decrypt and encrypt again because of the write wear on the SSD. If there's no other way then I suppose I'll go that route.

Comment: "Manually create partitions" corresponds to the old option 'Something else".

Comment: I think there is a way to install Ubuntu in the same encrypted partition where it was installed before. Someone may have written about it here, but I can't find it. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246401/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-with-full-disk-encryption-without-having-to-erase-every) may help.